# Como hacer referencia a un archivo ubicado en otro disco del servidor (G:/)?

Tags: html, html5

Tengo la carpeta del inetpub en un disco y los archivos que quiero dar el enlace para descargar en otro

Normalmente haria algo asi

```
<a href="https://dominio.com/recursos/imagen.jpg" download></a>
```

Y estaba pensando usar algo asi en este caso pero no funciona

```
 <a href="https://dominio.com/G:/recursos/imagen.jpg" download></a>
```

Comment: Para el navegador que cargue tu página le es indiferente la configuración de los discos que hay detrás del servidor que estés usando, Apache o IIS o nginx o el que sea. Él le pide recursos al servidor y éste se los entrega. No tiene sentido hablarle de recursos internos; es la configuración del servidor HTTP la que define qué va a exponer y qué no

Comment: Entiendo, gracias. @Alfabravo